# "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'NSNumber *'"

Tags: objective-c, ios

I suspect this is something really simple, but I'm trying to get an int that I have stored in a  dictionary and the line I'm using is this..

```
 int mapX = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[templateObject valueForKey:@"mapX"]];
```

But it's giving me the error...

> Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'id' to parameter
>   of type 'int'

and

> Incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an
>   expression of type 'NSNumber *';

If I try...

```
NSNumber *mapX = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[templateObject valueForKey:@"mapX"]];
```

I basically get the same error. I know I'm probably just using the wrong syntax, but I'm not sure how else to write it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

A couple of points:

- `[NSNumber numberWithInt:[templateObject valueForKey:@"mapX"]];`

  Returns an `NSNumber*`, which you're trying to store in an int.
- `NSNumber* mapX = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[templateObject valueForKey:@"mapX"]];`

  won't work either, because `[templateObject valueForKey:@"mapX"]` isn't an `int`. You can only store objects in `NSDictionary`, not primitive types.

You might want to try (Assuming I have the types correct)

```
NSNumber* mapXNum = [templateObject valueForKey:@"mapX"];
int mapX = [mapXNum intValue];
```

Comment: "then [templateObject valueForKey:@"mapX"] isn't an int either." - how could it be an integer **at all?** `NSDictionary` can hold objects only, not scalars.

Comment: "should really be [templateObject objectForKey:@"mapX"] unless you are certain you are using key-value coding" - this is also untrue, `NSDictionary` overrides `- valueForKey:` an it is equivalent to `- objectForKey:` if the key string doesn't begin with an `@` symbol (it seems to me that the `mapX` string doesn't begin with one).

Comment: My apologies, you're correct on `valueForKey`. Thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 5):

```
 int mapX = (int)[[templateObject valueForKey:@"mapX"] integerValue];
```

the above solution is assuming the templateObject valueForKey:@"mapX" returns an NSNumber.  If it doesn't and you want to convert it to an NSNumber, use this solution instead:

```
 int mapX = (int)[(NSNumber *)[templateObject valueForKey:@"mapX"] integerValue];
```

Typecasting in ObjC is the.worst.

Answer (score 1):

```
int mapX = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[templateObject valueForKey:@"mapX"]];
```

makes no sense for two reasons (think about it for a moment), however

```
NSNumber *mapX = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[templateObject valueForKey:@"mapX"] intValue]];
```

should work assuming `[templateObject valueForKey:@"mapX"]` is either an `NSNumber` or an `NSString` instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.  First, `[templateObject valueForKey:@"mapX"]` returns an `id`, which is a pointer to an Objective-C object, not an `int`.  And since the `-[NSNumber numberWithInt:]` method takes an `int` parameter, trying to convert an `id` to an `int` is an error.

The second problem is that you try to convert the result of `[NSNumber numberWithInt:...]` to an `int`, which is again the same problem: `-[NSNumber numberWithInt:]` returns a pointer to an `NSNumber` object, which is not an `int`.

Assuming that the value stored in your dictionary is in fact an `NSNumber`, what you really want to do is this:

```
NSNumber *mapXObj = [templateObject valueForKey:@"mapX"];  // Implicit cast from id to NSNumber*
int mapX = [mapXObj intValue];
```

Or more succinctly:

```
int mapX = [[templateObject valueForKey:@"mapX"] intValue];
```